# how to understand who wanted the result of a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two methods `alphaClicked()` and `betaClicked()` and for them to work we need to be connected to a service in the net so I have another method named `connect()` so in both classes we need to be connected first so we check if we are connected then if we are not then we call `connect()` method then we get the result of the connection in `ActionConnectionResultReceived` so if we connected successfully I want to call alphaClicked() if alpha was the one requesting the `connect()` and call `betaClicked()` if `betaClicked()` was the one requesting the `connect()` method what is the best way to do that?

To summarize this is the issue :

`alpha` and `beta` need to `connect` but `connect` result doesn't comes back immediately , so we get it via `ActionConnectionResultReceived` so , how to get who called the connect was it `alpha` or `beta`

```
private void alphaClicked()
{
    if(GooglePlayConnection.State == GPConnectionState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        Connect();
    }
}

private void betaClicked()
{
    if(GooglePlayConnection.State == GPConnectionState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        //do something else
    }
    else
    {
        Connect();
    }
}


private void ActionConnectionResultReceived(GooglePlayConnectionResult result)
{
    if (result.IsSuccess)
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected!");
        //if alpha requested call alpha if beta requested call beta
        //how to do this?
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Cnnection failed with code: " + result.code.ToString());
    }
}

private void Connect()
{
    GooglePlayConnection.Instance.Connect(); 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that alphaClicked/betaClicked will be called many times before the connection is established?

Comment: I Can prevent that from happening

Comment: Research *Dependency Injection*; it was invented for precisely this scenario.

Comment: How Dependency Injection can be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Without `Async` or `event handler`, and provided you only call one `connect` per time, you could introduce a variable which stores the last caller:

```
string gCaller = "";
private void Connect(string caller){
    gCaller = caller;
    //something else
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
private void alphaClicked()
{
   if(GooglePlayConnection.State == GPConnectionState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        //do something
    }
   else
   {
       Connect("alpha");
   }
}

private void betaClicked()
{
   if(GooglePlayConnection.State == GPConnectionState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        //do something else
    }
   else
   {
       Connect("beta");
   }
}
```

Then when you need the last one who creates the connection, you use the info in `gCaller`.

```
private void ActionConnectionResultReceived(GooglePlayConnectionResult result)
{
    if (result.IsSuccess)
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected!");
        switch (gCaller){
            case "alpha":
              alphaClicked();
              break;
            case "beta":
              betaClicked();
              break;
            default:
              break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Cnnection failed with code: " + result.code.ToString());
    }
}
```

But the best way would be to create `async` or event handler for `Connected` events. Take a look on this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: already implemented this way , wanted to know how I can do it in a cleaner way like `events` as you said

Comment: Then you may want to learn about `async` and `await`... or dependency injection (as Pieter suggested)